# SharePoint 2013 wiki page link pop up ( [[ ) only work for site administrator

Tags: wiki-pages, enterprise-wiki

I am trying to build a Enterprise wiki site on our SharePoint 2013 on-premise farm. When I login with site admin, by type in "[[" in edit mode, it automatically jump up the other wiki pages I built. (e.g. [[Animals/Dog )

However, when I am editing the same page with another user who have "edit" right, the automatically link fill up function no longer work. The user can still build wiki links if he know the path. He have access to all pages under /Pages library.

Why is that and how can I work around it?

Comment: Just found the tips here (http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20use%20wiki%20syntax%20to%20link%20to%20existing%20content%20and%20create%20pages.aspx). By CTRL+SPACE it force the pop-up menu. I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

I found the tips [here](http://mscerts.programming4.us/sharepoint/sharepoint%202010%20%20%20use%20wiki%20syntax%20to%20link%20to%20existing%20content%20and%20create%20pages.aspx).
By press CTRL+SPACE, and key in "[[" again, the wiki page link will prompt even you are not site administrator. I don't know why but it works.